# StackOverflow after 27 runs

Tags: stack-overflow, sudoku

When running my Sudoku Generator, after 27 times getting stack overflow.

```
void start(int todel){
int number;
for (int x=0; x<9; x++) {
    for (int y=0; y<9; y++) {

        number = GenN(x, y);
        osudoku[x][y]=number;
    }
}
replace(todel);
output();
}


int GenZ(int x, int y){
    int number;
    bool duplication = true;
    Randomize();
    number = Random(9)+1;
    duplication = check(number,x,y);
    if (duplication==true){
        return GenZ(x,y);
    }
    else if (duplication==false) {
        return number;
    }
}
```

I think its something with this code.
It generates things like:

```
758 431 629 
913 267 485 
642 985 317
Stack Overflow
```

So I get 1/3 Sudoku.

Comment: Please tag with the language used.

Comment: Shouldn't you assign `number` to something? Where is `zahl` coming from?

Comment: If you want to implement it by recursion, i suggest you pass on the set of remaining numbers. This way the recursion is guaranteed to run at maximum N (set size) steps. Each step you pick one number, remove it from the set and pass the remaining set on.

Comment: So in a recursive case you would pass the set of "numbers to pick from" as parameter together with a reference to the matrix where the numbers are put. Each step removes a random number from the set and puts it into the first free slot in the matrix , then passes those on until the "pick from" set is empty, then returns.

Comment: Should `number = GenN(x, y);` be `number = GenZ(x, y);`? Otherwise, what does `GenN` do and where is `GenZ` called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add [backtracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) to your solution.

Consider this scenario: (which may occur at some point in your algorithm)

```
1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
4 5 6 | 1 2 3 | ? _ _
...
```

Your program will just keep trying to find a value that fits at the `?`, but no such value exists.

Instead, your program needs to see that no values fits, and try a different value for `3`, which also won't work, then `2`, then `1` in which case it should eventually put `7`, `8` and `9` in the second block like:

```
1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9
4 5 6 | 7 8 9 | ? _ _
...
```

in which case it can continue successfully.

And this:

```
zahl = Random(9)+1;
```

won't really work as you may keep on getting values that don't fit (as in the above example). You won't know when to backtrack. It's better to loop through all 9 values. After you've looped through all 9 values, you'll know that no value fits and you'll know you must backtrack.

Comment: +1. You have to loop through all numbers, otherwise even if you generate all, you have no exit criterion (when no number fits anymore).

Answer (score 0):

if duplication==true in GenZ it will call it again with the same x,y , which will again produce duplication==true? especially since I cant see you modifying "number" , so it might be at it's initialized value like 0.

Comment: I cant see an assignment to "number" , the random number is assigned to "zahl"

Comment: Oh, sorry I didnt replace that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (duplication==true){
    return GenZ(x,y);
}
```

I am not sure if that is a viable way to create a sudoku, brute-forcing might take a while no matter how you implement it, but you can probably get rid off the stackoverflow error by not using recursion and having a loop.

```
while (duplication){
```